WPF TreeView with Scrollbar to fill remaining space in each TreeViewItem
I have a custom TreeViewItem class:
public partial class RessourceTreeViewItem : TreeViewItem
{
    public int RG_ID { get; set; }

    StackPanel taskPanel { get; set; }

    public String RGLabeltxt { get; set; }

    public Canvas backgroundcanvas { get; set; }

    public ScrollViewer scrollViewer { get; set; }

    public RessourceTreeViewItem(int RG_ID, double dots_per_minute, DateTime startdatetime, DateTime enddatetime)
    {
        this.RGLabeltxt = RGLabeltxt;
        this.RG_ID = RG_ID;

        this.taskPanel = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
        Label taskLabel = new Label() { 
            Content = this.RGLabeltxt 
        };

        taskLabel.Width = 40;

        this.backgroundcanvas = new Canvas();

        this.backgroundcanvas.Width = dots_per_minute * enddatetime.Subtract(startdatetime).TotalMinutes;
        this.backgroundcanvas.Height = 50;
        this.backgroundcanvas.Background = Brushes.White;

     
        this.scrollViewer = new ScrollViewer();
        this.scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible; 
        this.scrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
    

        this.scrollViewer.Content = this.backgroundcanvas;


        this.taskPanel.Children.Add(taskLabel);
        
        this.taskPanel.Children.Add(this.scrollViewer);

        this.Header = taskPanel;
        
    }
}

Here you can see a demo of my project:

The problem is:

I want the scrollView using the remaining space from taskLabel to the right window end. When I give it no value, as you can see, the scrollViews has max width and are not enabled, because the parent widget gets a scrollbar. I allready tried with a dockpanel and fillaviabledspace = true, but I had the same error.
I want to deaticate the margin at the front, because when I click in the TreeViewItem, the windows focuses on the taskpanel and scrolls automaticallly to the right at the beginning of the taskpanel.

Thank you!
